# Export Mixpanel Activity Feed Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, analytics, mixpanel

Is there any way to export Mixpanel's Activity Feed data into CSV form?

I need one sheet for each user, displaying all the activity that user has performed on my site.

I've seen many ways to export general user data and funnel reports but not much on user activity feeds. I am running a Ruby on Rails app but am happy to use a 3rd party tool or other method to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at least using **R** (see https://cran.r-project.org). The package *RMixpanel* (https://github.com/7factory/RMixpanel) provides the function *mixpanelGetEventsForProfiles* which imports the Activity Feed Data into an R data.frame. Exporting this to CSV is then an easy one-liner. Altogether it looks like:

```
> ## Install package.
> devtools::install_github("7factory/RMixpanel")
> require(RMixpanel)
> 
> ## Get people profiles.
> account <- mixpanelCreateAccount(...) ## TBD
> profiles <- mixpanelGetProfiles(account)
> 
> ## Load feed for 1st people profile.>
> distinctIDs = profiles[, "distinct_id"]
> feed001 <- mixpanelGetEventsForProfiles(account, distinctIDs[1])
>
> ## Save feed into CSV.
> write.table(feed001, "feed001.csv", quote=TRUE, sep=",", row.names=FALSE)
```